# Improving the code for Lemoine's conjecture

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

I am trying to improve the following code:

The code is written to solve the following equation:

```
2*n + 1 = p + 2*q
```

This equation denotes that given an integer number `n` the value `2*n + 1` always can be represented with `p + 2*q` where `p` and `q` are prime numbers.
This has been proved many years ago and is called `Lemoine's conjecture`.

The input to the code is a number (`n>2`) and the output would be a matrix including 2 columns of valid prime numbers.

```
n = 23;
S =  2*n+1;
P = primes(S);
V = [];
kk = 1;
for ii=1:length(P)
    for jj=1:length(P)
            if (S == P(ii)+2*P(jj))
                V(kk,:) = [P(ii) P(jj)];
                kk = kk + 1;
            end
    end
end
```

the result would be ;

```
V =

    13    17
    37     5
    41     3
    43     2
```

and for instance:

```
2*23+1 = 43 + 2*2
```

Is there a way to get rid of the for loops in MATLAB?

Update:

Suggested by @Daniel, also works

```
n = 23;
S =  2*n+1;
P = primes(S);
for ii=1:length(P)
    if ismember(S - P(ii),P)
        V(kk,:) = [P(ii) S-P(ii)];
    end
end
```

Comment: There is no need for two loops. `p = 2*n + 1 - 2*q`. Pick q and calculate p. Then check if p is in your array P.

Comment: Thanks, I've added what you have suggested.

Comment: @Daniel you were only a bit faster than I was ;-(
Anyway, if you iterate over the array of primes looking for a suitable `q`, you can stop as soon as `q > n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace those loops with a vectorized solution using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
[R,C] = find(bsxfun(@eq,P-S,-2*P(:)));
V = [P(C) ; P(R)].'
```

With `n = 100000`, the runtimes I got were -

```
------------ With loopy solution
Elapsed time is 33.789586 seconds.
----------- With bsxfun solution
Elapsed time is 1.338330 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a alternative implementation:

```
p_candidates=primes(2*n+1-4);
q_candidates=p_candidates(p_candidates<n+1);
p_needed=2*n+1-2*q_candidates;
solution=ismember(p_needed,p_candidates);
m=[q_candidates(solution);p_needed(solution)];
```

1. calulate upper bounds for p and q, start with the primes smaller than these bounds.
2. Choose q, calculate the corresponding value for p (p_needed).
3. Check if the needed value is a prime